# Select unique ids from multi values on one column in another table

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck for hours on an issue that might be pretty simple to solve but I'm just so lost...

I got 3 tables :

**user**

```
id    name
----------
1     jack
2     john
...
```

**car**

```
id    name
----------
1     ford
2     fiat
3     alfa
4     lada
...
```

**user_car**

```
id_user    id_car
-----------------
1          2
1          4
2          1
2          2
2          3
```

For example, i want to get all users with cars which have id 1 AND 2 in the **user_car** table so I should get the id_user 2 only and I can't find the proper way to do it.

Comment: IN (x,y) GROUP BY z HAVING COUNT(*) = 2

Comment: Well I think I found my way out by doing this : `SELECT user.id
FROM user
JOIN user_car uc1 ON uc1.id_car = 1
JOIN user_car uc2 ON uc2.id_car = 2
GROUP BY uc1.id_user;`

Answer (score 0):

try this untested query:

```
select * from user join user_car car1 on id =car1.user_id
join user_car car2 on id =car2.user_id  where car1.id_car=1 and car2.id_car=2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use UNION for this matter:

```
SELECT id as id_user from user where id in(1, 2)
UNION
SELECT id as id_car from car where id in (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you want this

```
SELECT *
FROM USER
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT id_user
     FROM user_car
     WHERE id_car=1 OR id_car=2);
```

Comment: Can you post what is your expected output?

Comment: For this to work you would need an OR rather than an AND in the sub query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use COUNT to do this:-

```
SELECT user.name
FROM user
INNER JOIN user_car ON user.id = user_car.id_user
INNER JOIN car ON user_car.id_car = car.id
WHERE car.id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY user.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT car.id) = 2
```

Note that this could be simplified to remove the need for the car table when you are just using the id of the car.